# How can I get rid of x on the exponents so as to solve this inequality?

Tags: inequality, logarithms, exponential-function

I came across the following inequality:

$\sqrt[2x]{\left | 4^{x}-12 \right |}\geq \sqrt[x]{2}$

my problem with it is that I can't get rid of the power root x without losing solutions. As a matter of fact, my result is:

$x\leq 2 \cup x\leq 3/2-\left \{ 0 \right \}$

while the real solution is:

$\forall x \in \mathbb{N}-\left \{ 0 \right \}$

can anyone please tell me what I'm missing ?

Comment: Can you tell us where this problem comes from? The answer should be $x\in(0,3/2)\cup(2,\infty)$.

Comment: I can attach the file, the excersise in number 267 page 591 : http://www.profmarenco.net/registro2/terzaG/matematica/Esponenziali%20e%20Logaritmi.pdf

Comment: It appears that the text is allowing $\sqrt[x]{\cdot}$ to be defined only for $x\in\mathbb N-\{0\}$. You may be able to find somewhere in the text where they define $x$th roots to confirm this. If so, then the interval I gave above, restricted to the integers, is precisely $x\in\mathbb N-\{0\}$.

Comment: I see what you mean, thank you